# Generar un archivo JSON desde PHP

Tags: php, json

Estoy conectando con mi base de datos, pero no quiero que me muestre el resultado en la plantilla de la página sino que me genere un fichero `.json`.

El código PHP que uso es:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM AttributeKeys WHERE atID = 1"; 

function connectDB(){

    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "user";
    $pass = "pass";
    $bd = "bd";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd);

return $conexion;
}

function disconnectDB($conexion){

$close = mysqli_close($conexion);  

return $close;
}

function getArraySQL($sql){
//Creamos la conexión con la función anterior
$conexion = connectDB();

//generamos la consulta
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); 

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die(); 

$rawdata = array();

//guardamos en un array multidimensional todos los datos de la consulta
$i=0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rawdata[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}

disconnectDB($conexion); //desconectamos la base de datos

return $rawdata; //devolvemos el array
}
    $myArray = getArraySQL($sql);
    echo json_encode($myArray);
?>
```

¿Cómo podría resolver esto?

Comment: O has copiado mal el fichero, o tienes una errata después del return $rawdata; porque el cierre } de la función aparece comentado

Comment: gracias, he corregido la errata pero sigo igual, necesito generar otro fichero .json

Comment: ¿Pero qué error te da? Intenta explicarnos qué hace este código y qué le falta para conseguir lo que quieres

Comment: ¿Cómo se llamaría el archivo JSON que deseas crear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para escribir el contenido del JSON en un archivo cuyo nombre tenga que relación con el `id` de la página puedes hacer lo siguiente al final de tu código:

```
<?php
$myArray = getArraySQL($sql);
// echo json_encode($myArray);
file_put_contents('js/ui0001.json', json_encode($myArray));
```

He hecho uso de la función [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) que guarda en el archivo dado en el primer parámetro la información proporcionada en el segundo (en este caso, el array codificado en JSON).

El código asume que el directorio donde deseas guardar los archivos JSON (`js`) esté previamente creado y se disponga de permisos para escribir en ella.

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería funcionar

```
<?php 
$sql="select * ...."; 

$response = array();
$posts = array();
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  $title=$row['title']; 
  $url=$row['url']; 
  $posts[] = array('title'=> $title, 'url'=> $url);
} 
$response['posts'] = $posts;
$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Saludos :)

Answer (score -1):

error no me da, cuando lanzo la pagina me muestra asi en mi gestor de contenidos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero lo que quiero conseguir es que la pagina se quede en blanco, y genere un archivo en esta carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el nombre del archivo podria ser por ejemplo el id de la pagina ui0001.json

Comment: Hola Cristian, lo que deberías de hacer es [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/194527/edit) tu pregunta, no añadir una respuesta con mas información. Por otro lado el codigo o mensajes de error siempre se han de poner como texto, no como imagen.